# Azure Cache Redis Large total connections received status

Tags: azure, redis, azure-caching

I have new Azure redis-cache app and I've been monitoring it for days now. I'm checking how my redis app is performing by using redis-cli command "[INFO](https://redis.io/commands/info)"

```
redis.cache.windows.net:6379> INFO
```

Everything looks fine except for the `total_connections_received` stats, see sample screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjBPw.jpg).It says that my `total_connections_received:4020498` at the moment and it keeps growing rapidly.

> total_connections_received: Total number of connections accepted by
>   the server ([source](https://redis.io/commands/info))

```
2:00 P.M : total_connections_received:4020498 
3:00 P.M : total_connections_received:4027593
```

after an hour it grows **7,095**

I also checked the application that connects to my redis app and it doesn't flood the connection. On average there is 50 to 150 connection per day and so I'm sure it is not my application fault.

Why is my `total_connections_received` increasing rapidly?

[Here is my duplicate question at superuser : https://superuser.com/questions/1454807/azure-redis-cache-growing-total-connections-received]

**EDIT :**

I'm monitoring the server using [monitor command](https://redis.io/commands/monitor) and sees nothing wrong happening. no connectiong flooding the server.

```
redis.cache.windows.net:6379> MONITOR
```

Comment: are you sure that the application/client you are using is not connection/disconnecting to the redis-server. because `total_connections_received` increases whenever a new connection is created.No matter if it is an existing client or new.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I tried running a redis server in my local machine and monitored the `total_connections_received` and it was normal.

Comment: By normal I mean, the connection count is not flooded with 7,000 connections an hour.